# Seeking Solutions for Generating Text Descriptions from Diagrams, Infographics, Charts, etc

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition, generative-models, text-generation

I am currently on a quest to find an efficient way to generate meaningful text descriptions (or alt text) from visual representations such as diagrams, infographics, charts, plots and the like. Ideally, the solution would be able to provide detailed analysis in textual form, similar to: "a bar chart with the x axis ranging from \$0 to \$500B and the y-axis from 2005 to 2018. The graph also incorporates a line graph showing deal count increasing from \$250B to \$395B between 2005 and 2007...", etc.

My current attempts with AWS Rekognition haven't been quite satisfactory, as the output is limited to general labels such as "chart" or "plot", lacking the detailed interpretation that I'm aiming for.

I am considering exploring Amazon SageMaker's image-to-text models and fine-tuning them with labeled charts. However, I'm unsure about the feasibility of this approach, in terms of data requirements and the level of accuracy it could potentially deliver.

Has anyone encountered a similar challenge and found a successful solution, either by developing a custom solution or using an existing service or model? Any insights or advice related to this would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, if anyone has an estimate on the volume of data required for successful fine-tuning of an image-to-text model to achieve this goal, that would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance for your valuable input.

Comment: I think you are aiming way past what's possible with the current state of the art. Who knows, maybe GPT-4 can do such things when OpenAI releases the image input access, but certainly not with what is available today (June 2023).

Comment: That's the impression I'm getting too @noe. But it seems like some projects are getting close, like https://huggingface.co/google/matcha-plotqa-v2